# pylab scilimits not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a simple graph in with python 2.7's matplotlib module.

The problem I'm having is that the function `ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='y',scilimits=(-3.0e-6,-1.0e-6))` is not applying the given scilimit values. I've tried turning off the autoscaling before and after the plot command

If I use the values in the `ylim` function it does work, but it won't be in scientific notation. Any help would be hot.

```
from pylab import *

v=[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]
i=[-1.57e-6,-1.8e-6,-1.97e-6,-2.18e-6,-2.30e-6]


plot(v,i,"bo")
autoscale(enable=False)
xlim(-6,0)
#ylim(-3e-6,-1e-6)
ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='y',scilimits=(-3.0e-6,-1.0e-6))

xlabel("Voltage/(V)")
ylabel("Current/(A)")
title("Current vs Voltage \n(Schottky Reverse Bias)")
grid()
show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gca().ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='y',scilimits=(0,0))
ylim(-3e-6,-1e-6)
```